# Laravel: In what situations would a service call a view, instead of a controller handling both calling the service and then calling the view?

Tags: php, design-patterns, model-view-controller, laravel, laravel-4

Take a moment and consider the following Laravel controller:
    class UsersController extends Controller {

```
    public function index()
    {
        // some index stuff

    }

    public function ajax()
    {
       // This is how I like to do CRUD

       if(Input::get('action') == "edit"){
           return $this->edit(Input::get('id'));
       }

       if(Input::post('action') == "update"){
           return $this->update(Input::all());
       }

       ...
    }

    private function edit($id)
    {
        // Let's populate an edit users dialog (popup)

        $viewData = array();

        // Call edit method of my Users service & send that data to view
        // (Note: "with" is a Laravel Helper)
        return View::make('users.usersEdit', with(new Users)->edit($id));

        // Or should I just have the service take care of the view, like this:
        // return with(new Users)->edit($id);   
    }
}
```

In the spirit of "skinny controllers, fat services"...(my spin on the slogan)...
If I feel very confident that the edit method of my **Users** service (not shown here) is always going to need it's corresponding view, should I have the view called from the service (instead of calling the view from my **UsersController** as shown above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is not a **requirement** for your edit user method, it is the output of the **result**. `Users` is domain logic. It should ideally have little to no dependency on Laravel, so you could stick it into another framework with little to no modification.

A controller is the perfect place to return Views. Definitely not in your domain logic. :)

Comment: Ah...because we want to say that a service could potentially support other views. And we want to keep separation as much as possible, from the domain logic. Ok, just needed this extra confidence from other SO users. Perhaps this question will help others as well. Thank you.

Comment: Your domain logic / service shouldn't care about any views. It's designed to do a specific task and that's it. Your controller calls the service, passing any relevant input, then based on the result, outputs something to the user. But yeah, sounds like you've got it. :)